# Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double

Tags: java, compare, comparable, compareto

The line `return array[index1].compareTo(array[index2]);` provides an error **"Cannot invoke compareTo(double) on the primitive type double"**. How to solve this issue?

```
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
/*::  This function implements a comparator of double values        :*/
/*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
private class ArrayIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    private final double[] array;

    public ArrayIndexComparator(double[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public Integer[] createIndexArray()
    {
        Integer[] indexes = new Integer[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            indexes[i] = i; // Autoboxing
        }
        return indexes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2)
    {
         // Autounbox from Integer to int to use as array indexes
        return array[index1].compareTo(array[index2]);
    }
}


double[] dist = new double[centroids.size()];
// fill array...    
ArrayIndexComparator comparator = new ArrayIndexComparator(dist);
Integer[] indexes = comparator.createIndexArray();
Arrays.sort(indexes, comparator);
```

Comment: To explore more visit the java documentation and within that go to the package java.lang.Double, this is called a Wrapper class and in Java for every primitive type there are corresponding wrapper classes are present under the java.lang package

Comment: Here is the link for documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Replace the call of an instance method `compareTo` with the call of [static `compare` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29), like this:

```
return Double.compare(array[index1], array[index2]);
```

This lets you keep your `double`s in an array of primitives, and avoid autoboxing before calling an instance method.

Comment: How to sort in reverse order in this case? Where to put ,Collections.reverseOrder()?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos `Collections.reverseOrder()` is for reversing the natural order. Since you are using a comparator, you can switch the order inside it by calling `Double.compare(array[index2], array[index1])`, or by adding an extra `boolean isReverseOrder` flag to the constructor, storing it in a member variable, and inverting the comparison result inside the `compare` method when `isReverseOrder` is set.

Answer (score 1):

In java primitive types don't have any methods. Instead using primitive data types use Wrapper classes.

change

```
return array[index1].compareTo(array[index2]);
```

to

```
return  new Double(array[index1]).compareTo(array[index2]);
```

**or**

try with  `Double[] array;` instead of    `double[] array;`

Answer (score 0):

for primitive types do not use `compareTo`, use `==` instead

but if you want to use `compareTo` just create a Double array

```
Double[] dist = new Double[centroids.size()];
```

Comment: `==` is not an equivalent of `compareTo` but of `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive Types cannot be compared directly by a comparator, as the interface is only implemented by collator and RuleBasedCollator. No wrapper class implements comparator.  Due to which compiler won't be able to auto box it.

Just look in Double class and you will find an inbuilt method which provides compare method.

`public static int compare(double d1, double d2)`

**Returns:**
the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2.

**Reverse:** Multiple the entire expression by -1;