# Sort Three Arrays by ArrayList Index (Row) on a Single Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, collections

In an ArrayList I have three double[ ] arrays that I wish to sort on the third array. The third array is also unsorted.

```
public class LevelList extends ArrayList<double[]> {
```

My comparator [compares doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142192/cannot-invoke-comparetodouble-on-the-primitive-type-double):

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Linearize {
     static final Comparator<double[]> RATIO_ORDER = 
             new Comparator<double[]>() {
                 @Override
                 public int compare(double[] d1, double[] d2) {
                     //Sort the ratios based on the fraction column 2
                     return Double.compare(d1[2], d2[2]);
                 }
         };
}
```

I then call:

```
Collections.sort(levelList, Linearize.RATIO_ORDER);
levelList.println();
```

However, this only results in a sorting of the order of arrays in ArrayList.

In pseudocode, what I wish to achieve is:

```
For Each Row of ArrayList at Index i
Sort on Array 3
```

So that this input:

```
[1.0][2.0][2.1]
[2.0][5.0][2.2]
[1.0][5.0][1.0]
```

becomes:

```
[1.0][5.0][1.0]
[1.0][2.0][2.1]
[2.0][5.0][2.2]
```

because: 2.2 > 2.1 > 1.0

Comment: what's the desired output?

Comment: I have demonstrated this under "becomes:" above. Each array should be presented in a column, sorted on the third.

Comment: I thought that was the output you already got.

Comment: What I got is actually Col1 Col2 Col3 sorts to Col2 Col3 Col1, I guess depending on each column value.

Comment: Why `extends ArrayList`?  Avoid extending classes from the collections framework.

Comment: I tried your code and the output I got for the input `[1.0, 2.0, 2.1]
[2.0, 5.0, 2.2]
[1.0, 5.0, 1.0]` was `[1.0, 5.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 2.1]
[2.0, 5.0, 2.2]`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desired output. I tested the following code. Did not understand why levellist has to extend arraylist, hence removed that.

```
public class TestLevelSorting {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<double[]> levelList = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    double[] items1 = {1.0, 2.01, 2.1};
    double[] items2 = {2.0, 5.0, 2.2};
    double[] items3 = {1.0, 5.0, 1.0};

    levelList.add(items1);
    levelList.add(items2);
    levelList.add(items3);

    Collections.sort(levelList, Linearize.RATIO_ORDER);

    for(double[] item : levelList){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item));
    }
}
}

class Linearize {
static final Comparator<double[]> RATIO_ORDER = new Comparator<double[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(double[] d1, double[] d2) {
        // Sort the ratios based on the fraction column 2
        return Double.compare(d1[2], d2[2]);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: This works for the example. However, the actual arrays are much longer than in the example. When inserting the actual arrays, the output looks transposed. I am not sure why. Is there a way to return only the head (i.e. first 5 rows) with a loop?

Comment: Oops. I initialized the size incorrectly. And from there on it was simply:

    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
       for(int o = 0; o < 3; o++){
       System.out.print(levelList.get(o)[i] + ", ");
      }
   System.out.println();
     }