# working with Collections and cannot get compareTo() method working

Tags: java, collections

I want to sort based on the weights and the compareTo() method is not working, but when I change the weight type to "Integer" in my POJO it works. Can someone please explain to me what is happening? Please find my code below

```
public class CollectionsDemo {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                List<Apple> appleList = Arrays.asList(
                                            new Apple(10, "green"),
                                            new Apple(60, "green"),
                                            new Apple(150, "green"),
                                            new Apple(155, "red"),
                                            new Apple(175, "red"),
                                            new Apple(110, "green"));
    
            //sorting
            appleList.sort(new Comparator<Apple>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Apple o1, Apple o2) {
                    return o1.getWeight().compareTo(o2.getWeight()); //compareTo() won't come up in suggestions
                    //return o1.getColor().compareTo(o2.getColor()); //this is working
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
        public class Apple {
        
            private int weight; //changing to Integer works
            private String color;
            
            //getters
            //setters
        
        }
```

Comment: You cannot call to `compareTo` method on a primitive type. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142192/cannot-invoke-comparetodouble-on-the-primitive-type-double

Comment: `Comparator.comparingInt(Apple::getWeight).thenComparing(Apple::getColor)`.

Comment: `int` is a primitive type and does not have methods at all.

Answer (score 1):

As an integer (`int`) is a primitive in Java, it doesn't (and can't) implement the `Comparable` interface. You should use the `Integer.compare` method which compares as follows:

```
(x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: subtracting is dangerous (fails for very large numbers due to overflow). `Integer.compare` is the _only_ right answer - please update.

Comment: What a terrible oversight, I'll edit my answer. Thank you @rzwitserloot.